# The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Margins?'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

My flutter project used to run fine but after I update my flutter sdk to 3.3.4 I am getting two errors and couldn't compile the project.

> The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Margins?'.

```
FittedBox(
                      child: Html(
                        data: article.title,
                        style: {
                          'body': Style(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            fontSize: _articleTileFont(context),
                            lineHeight: const LineHeight(1.4),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            maxLines: 3,
                            textOverflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
```

I am using EdgeInsets.zero in multiple files but it is always throwing a error after I have updated.

[image: EdgeInsets Error]

Another Error I am getting is:

> The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.

```
FontSize _articleTileFont(BuildContext context) {
    if (Responsive.isMobile(context)) {
      return const FontSize(25);
    } else if (Responsive.isTabletPortrait(context)) {
      return const FontSize(48);
    } else if (Responsive.isTablet(context)) {
      return const FontSize(65);
    } else {
      return const FontSize(25);
    }
  }
```

[image: The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.]

There is the same error on many pages. Please help me.

Comment: Neither `Style` nor `FontSize` are classes in the flutter framework. It must be from some package you use. Upgrading flutter is not what caused this, but the upgrading of that package

Comment: Thank You. But what can I do now can you help me????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove the `const` wherever it complains about it. And you can replace

```
margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

with

```
margin: Margins.zero,
```

These are changes in the `flutter_html` package that you are using

Comment: Thank You It worked can you help me for another one: The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.

Comment: @Punkkk just remove the word `const`

Comment: Thank You !!! Solved. Huge FAN of yours.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing ? I am getting error "There's no constant named 'NORMAL' in 'WhiteSpace'."  ( Code: whiteSpace: WhiteSpace.NORMAL,)

Comment: @Punkkk that should be `WhiteSpace.normal`. in small letters. It's really not hard to see yourself. When something doesn't exist just look at what does exist. Writing `WhiteSpace.` will give you suggestions of what could go after it. Or simply look at what `WhatSpice` looks like by ctrl + clicking it

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try to add `const` in your code like

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.zero,
```

2.You have to remove const so that you text  size will be responsive

```
FontSize _articleTileFont(BuildContext context) {
       if (Responsive.isMobile(context)) {
       return  FontSize(25);
     } else if (Responsive.isTabletPortrait(context)) {
      return  FontSize(48);
    } else if (Responsive.isTablet(context)) {
      return  FontSize(65);
      } else {
         return  FontSize(25);
     }
      }
```

Comment: I tried as you say. But its not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: are you using any packages in this class?